# Connection error! Please try again... wordpress admin panel

Tags: wordpress

After admin login in wordpress site, i got the following error message in all pages at top

Connection error! Please try again...

I got the error after install the plugin updraftplus. Could you please tell me how can i remove this error message in admin panel?

Comment: Please make WP_DEBUG true in wp-config.php file to check the exact issue

Answer (score 0):

You should deactivate or delete the plugin first. If you use FTP, you can remove the installed plugin under **wp-content/plugins/** directory. If your website in localhost, you can delete the installed plugin in your computer under **wp-content/plugins/** folder.

Comment: Site is in live mode. We need this plugin.

Comment: May be you may use another plugin similar as Updraftplus. Some of the plugins are not compatible with themes and Wordpress version.

Comment: when we call this function do_action( 'admin_menu', '' ); in wp-admin/includes/menu.php only we got this error

Comment: Alright. I recommend should not touch wp-admin folder even we have to edit something inside.